# IntelliJ junit5 run configuration - run all tests with a tag, AND in a particular package

Tags: intellij-idea, junit5

As far as I can tell, I can run all tests in a package, OR all tests with a tag.  I want to combine the two.  Is there a way in the UI that I'm just not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-245281
That is the subtask of https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153780. Thanks